# T-SQL: Is the variable NVARCHAR(MAX)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the actual type of a column or variable in t-sql?

I know about `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY`, but this fails miserably for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`:

```
DECLARE @foo1 NVARCHAR(10) = N'a'
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo1, 'BaseType') --works fine
DECLARE @foo2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'a'
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo2, 'BaseType') --fails with an error:
--Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with sql_variant
```

Is there anything else that is able to tell me if a variable contains a value of the type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?

Some background:

I am working on a procedure that should reorder the columns of a table: Rename the old table, create a new one, copy the data and drop the old one. In order to do this, all indexes, views, constraints, etc. need to be recreated on the new table.

I want to make sure that nothing gets lost in this automatic process. For that, I would like to copy most values from the relevant system-tables to a generic temp-table and compare the values after the reordering. This works perfectly fine now, but it fails when trying to detect the type of nvarchar(max)-columns.

Comment: what is the error you get?  (I know what it is, but it should be a part of the question)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969508/operand-type-clash

Comment: @Kritner: Added the error-message

Comment: trying to understand when you would need this -- if it is a local variable then you define it in the code.  If it is a column there are other ways to find out the type information.

Comment: Are you trying to get the length of a VARCHAR field?

Comment: @Hogan: I am dealing with the sys-tables and a string-list of column-names that should be copied to a temp-table. Unfortunately, the sys-tables do not contain meta-info about the sys-tables.

Comment: Hopefully you understand why it is a very bad idea to reorder columns in a table? This is a requirement I would push back, it is bound to cause bugs and data integrity issues from hidden bugs. All it takes is one person using select * from this to cause problems.

Comment: @HLGEM: In our team, we decided to live with the few bugs ocurring now instead of living with oddly ordered columns forever. But we do also have an architecture and coding-conventions, that make it very hard to create bugs from "select *" or similar stuff. Actually, we did not have a single bug since we are doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Andreas,

If you are looking to discover the data type and length of the column then you could use the following code.
Note that -1 is used where (max) is stated in the schema.
Add a WHERE clause in to specify table or column name

```
SELECT      tb.name TableName, cl.name ColumnName
            , cl.system_type_id, ty.name, cl.max_length
FROM        sys.columns cl
INNER JOIN  sys.tables tb ON tb.object_id = cl.object_id
INNER JOIN  sys.types ty ON cl.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
ORDER BY    cl.max_length
```

Answer (score 0):

**sql_variant can not store nvarchar(max) and Sql_variant does support strings**

it will not store this types also

```
varchar(max)
varbinary(max)
nvarchar(max)
xml
text
```

etc...

instead of go to

```
nvarchar(4000) but not nvarchar(max).
varchar(8000) but not varchar(max)
```

Comment: I am willing to do that, but I need to know the type of the variable first. This is generic code that gets the value from a sys-table (sys.columns does not contain information about these columns) and should store it in a sql_variant. But in order to do the conversion for the correct columns only, I need to know the type.